# Comparing histograms, Normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian

I want to apply the *X*^2 test to a distribution. For that I have create a Gaussian distribution with the median and standard deviation same as my original distribution so it can act as the theoretical model. I have my original distribution which is an array and then turn it into an histogram with 20 bins.

```
bin = 20
od = np.array([1,2,3,34,5,...6,6])
oh = np.histogram(od,bin)
```

Now to make a histogram of the expected values (normal distribution) I have given the average of each bin in the original histogram a probability from the normal distribution.

```
x = []
y = []
for e in range(0,bin):
    x.append(od[1][i]+od[1][i+1]/2)
for e in x:
    y.append(gaussian(e,od.mean(),od.std())
```

Then plot it

```
plt.bar(x,y)
```

The problem is that the histogram's y values don't add up to 1, if they did I could just multiply them by the number of elements in the original histogram to be able to compare them. How can I do this?

Comment: parameter: ```density : bool, optional```
If False, the result will contain the number of samples in each bin. If True, the result is the value of the probability density function at the bin, normalized such that the integral over the range is 1. Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen; it is not a probability mass function.